# Visual studio profiling does not see symbols for vsperf .vspx file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, profiling

I used vsperf from command line to profiling service running on certain machine. I copied the generated .vspx file from profiled system to development machine. I opened it using visual studio 2015 and profiling analyzer does fails to load symbols for my binaries.

If I use remote debugging to attach to process from the same Visual Studio to same process debugger does see symbols.

I copied PDB files to profiled machine and add to _NT_SYMBOL_PATH and run vsperf again, sill no symbols.

I added PDB directories to settings everywhere I could see in visual studio. Still no symbols for profiling report.

Is it possible to get verbose log of profiling analyzer to see why exactly it fails to load symbols?

Is it possible to see how debugger loads symbols and tell profiling analyzer to load exactly the same symbols?